# Matlab: Getting the Coefficients of Piecewise Cubic Hermite Interpolating Polynomial

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, coefficients

I want to fit a curve to some data. I used a PCHIP interpolation because of getting the best results. Moreover, I want to get the coefficients for the 6 intervals with the `ppval-function`. But there pops up an error like these:

```
Error using unmkpp (line 18)
The input array does not seem to describe a pp function.

Error in ppval (line 62)
[b,c,l,k,dd]=unmkpp(pp);

Error in SA (line 8)
v = ppval(p,xdata)
```

This is my code:

```
clear all
xdata = [0; 3.5; 6.8; 7.6; 8.2; 30; 34.2];
ydata = [0; 50; 400000; 2000000; 25000000; 100000000;100000000]
xq1 = 0:0.01:35;

p = pchip(xdata,ydata, xq1);
s = spline(xdata,ydata,xq1);
v = ppval(p,xdata)
plot(xdata,ydata,'o',xq1,p,'-',xq1,s,'-.');
legend('Datenpunkte','pchip','spline','Location','SouthEast');
```

Can you help me?

Best regards
Dominik

Answer (score 1):

[`pchip`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pchip.html#description) has two working modes:

- Calculating the piecewise polynomial coefficients: `pp = pchip(x,y)`:

  > returns a piecewise polynomial structure for use with `ppval`
- Interpolating at specified points: `p = pchip(x,y,xq)`:

  > is the same as `p = ppval(pchip(x,y),xq)`
  >
  > returns a vector of interpolated values p corresponding to the query
  >   points in xq

So, you are using the second mode, which is not suited for use with `ppval`.